# How to groupby the first level index and apply function to the second index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have multilevel dataframe 'df' like this :

```
             col1 col2
first second
a        0    5    5
         1    5    5
         2    5    5
b        0    5    5
         1    5    5
```

And I want to apply a function `func` (exp: `'lambda x: x*10'`) to `second`, somewhat like :

```
df.groupby(level='first').second.apply(func)
```

and result will lokk like:

```
             col1 col2
first second
a        0    5    5
         10   5    5
         20   5    5
b        0    5    5
         10   5    5
```

The above command not work for `second` is not a column, so `.second` is not accepted by Pandas .

I don't want to do that by `df.reset_index()` , blablabla..., then finally `df.set_index().` I prefer to do it in one command, How to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the DataFrame, you could set the MultiIndex as follows:

```
df.set_index(['first', 'second'], drop=False)
```

This way, the index column is not dropped and still accessible for your `apply`.

Comment: i know, but the dataframe looks somewhat having 'duplicate' contents. I strongly suggest Pandas developers can treat index_column the same way as the normal column, use the same syntax to slice/fliter/groupby/.... index_column and common column. SQL database 'select/update/..' key_column the same way as non_key_column, why Pandas not adopt the same philosophy ?

Comment: @bigbug Exactly. It is such a pain to have to refactor code to use completely different methods, functions, and approaches depending on whether the value you want is an index or a column. This gets really annoyingly messy when running `groupby()` operations, especially on a `MultiIndex` and `apply()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `set_levels` method of the index to change the values in a given level. So for a given `func` and `level` you can do:

```
new_values = map(func, df.index.get_level_values(level))
df.index.set_levels(new_values, level, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more explanation how this works (and also, I'm assuming the * 10 was meant to show the example function  ... would df.index.set_levels(func(df.index.get_level_values(1)),1,inplace=True) work in for an arbitrary function func)

Comment: I generalised the answer as requested. I forgot that the `*10` was only meant as a simple representative example.